# Ansible merge list with dict

Tags: list, dictionary, merge, ansible

I have below playbook in which I search for all vars starting with `static_routes__` and then merge them.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    static_routes__host:
      management:
        - address: '0.0.0.0/0'
          next_hop: '192.168.0.1'

    static_routes__lab:
      management:
        - address: '1.1.1.1/32'
          next_hop: '192.168.0.1'

    static_routes__test:
      test:
        - address: '8.8.8.8/32'
          next_hop: '192.168.2.1'

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        static_routes: "{{ static_routes | default({}) | combine(lookup('vars', item, default={}), recursive=True, list_merge='append') }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'static_routes__') }}"

    - name: Output static_routes
      debug:
        var: static_routes
```

The above will result in:

```
TASK [Output static_routes] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "static_routes": {
        "management": [
            {
                "address": "0.0.0.0/0",
                "next_hop": "192.168.0.1"
            },
            {
                "address": "1.1.1.1/32",
                "next_hop": "192.168.0.1"
            }
        ],
        "test": [
            {
                "address": "8.8.8.8/32",
                "next_hop": "192.168.2.1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However the `merge_list_` is only available in Ansible version > 2.9, which is currently not available to me due to company policies. I'm looking for a way to replicate above output in Ansible version =< 2.9.

With the below task I'm able to sort of reproduce it but it only allows one list item.

```
- set_fact:
    static_routes: "{{ static_routes | default({}) | combine({vrf: route | default([]) }) }}"
  loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'static_routes__') }}"
  vars:
    vrf: "{{ lookup('dict', lookup('vars', item)).key }}"
    route: "{{ lookup('dict', lookup('vars', item)).value }}"
    subnet: "{{ lookup('dict', lookup('vars', item)).value.0.address }}"
    next_hop: "{{ lookup('dict', lookup('vars', item)).value.0.next_hop }}"

- name: Output static_routes
  debug:
    var: static_routes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
- set_fact:
    static_routes_list: "{{ static_routes_list | default({}) | combine({item: lookup('vars', item)}) }}"
  loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'static_routes__') }}"

- set_fact:
    static_routes: "{{ static_routes|
                       default({})|
                       combine({item.0: item.1|json_query('[].value')|flatten | unique})
                       }}"
  loop: "{{ static_routes_list|
            dict2items|
            json_query('[*].value')|
            map('dict2items')|list|flatten|
            groupby('key')
            }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one seems simpler

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _list: "{{ _list|default([]) + [lookup('vars', item)] }}"
      loop: "{{ query('varnames', 'static_routes__') }}"
    - set_fact:
        static_routes: "{{ static_routes|default({})|
                           combine({item.0: item.1|json_query('[].value')|flatten}) }}"
      loop: "{{ _list|map('dict2items')|map('first')|groupby('key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  static_routes:
    management:
    - address: 0.0.0.0/0
      next_hop: 192.168.0.1
    - address: 1.1.1.1/32
      next_hop: 192.168.0.1
    test:
    - address: 8.8.8.8/32
      next_hop: 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Thanks again Vladimir for this great solution. I've added `| unique` after `flatten` so it only gives me unique routes.